# How to properly create a new object that is a copy of another?

Tags: javascript

I recall being able to clone an object with the spread operator like such:

```
let obj1 = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2'  
}

let obj2 = { ...obj1 }
```

But now I realize this doesn't work as I am trying to change values of obj2 and its also changing the values in obj1.

If I did:

```
obj2.key2 = 'test'
```

It would change obj1.key2 to 'test' as well.

Why is this happening?

I also tried doing:

```
let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1)
```

but i face the same issues.

Thanks

```
let obj1 = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

let obj2 = { ...obj1 }

obj2.key2 = 'changed key2 value'

console.log( obj1.key2 == obj2.key2 )
```

Comment: Ummmm, Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay. working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're only half right. What you're doing is called a "shallow clone", and it copies all properties of an object to another one. Now, if those properties are primitives (numbers / strings), then you can safely change them on one object without altering the other. But for objects or arrays, you're actually copying their reference. So if `testKey` is an object, when you do `obj1.testKey` you're referring to the same object as if you do `obj2.testKey`.

In order to do what's called a "deep clone" so that this doesn't happen, you have 2 options.

Either spread over those objects manually, like this:

```
let obj1 = {
    key: {
        value: 1
    },
    key2: 2
}

let obj2 = {
    ...obj2,
    key: {
        ...obj1.key
    }
}
```

This can get really tiring, specially with big structures or more levels of nesting. The second option, which I recommend, is using lodash `cloneDeep`: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep

Answer (score 0):

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```
syntax:
    Object.assign(target, ...sources)
    target: The target object.
    sources: The source object(s).
    Return value: The target object.
```

```
let a = {}
let b = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2'  
}

Object.assign(a, b)
a.key2 = '123'
console.log(a.key2 == b.key2) // false
// a: {key: "value", key2: "123"}
// b: {key: "value", key2: "value2"}
```

or

```
let b = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2'  
}

let a = Object.assign({}, b)
a.key2 = '123'
console.log(a.key2 == b.key2) // false
// a: {key: "value", key2: "123"}
// b: {key: "value", key2: "value2"}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because assign() only creates a reference (pointer) to the original object. So if you change the reference object, you change the original. To completely copy an object, I typically convert the object to JSON and then back to a new object:

```js
let obj1 = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2'
}

console.log("Ojbect 1, key:" + obj1.key);

let obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));

obj2.key = "new_value";

console.log("Object 1, key:" + obj1.key);
console.log("Object 2, key:" + obj2.key);
```

Comment: Wow, ok. Mind explaining why I was downvoted?

Comment: This is not a good solution, as it's quite slower than simply iterating the object recursively to perform a deep clone. Also, if any of the properties are not serializable, your "clone" will not be an exact copy of the original. For example, if you have an object like `{ date: new Date() }`

Comment: @CertainPerformance According to [this](http://jsben.ch/bWfk9), lodash deep clone is faster.